# Make changes in Ubuntu 16.04 installation sequence?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, system-installation, scripts, usb-installation

I need to install drivers or update settings after completing the Ubuntu installation;

e.g. Installing the Wifi driver by using following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms_*.deb    
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb
```

or adding languages to the keyboard layout, and etc.

Is there any way to change the 'Ubuntu installation sequence' in order to include those commands within the Ubuntu installation sequence?

Is there any file ( .sh or whatever), or script, or etc. in the Ubuntu installation USB containing commands that the system needs to run for proceeding and completing the Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubiquity package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) is used to install Ubuntu and other versions of Linux, but its [preseeding options are limited](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopCDOptions), as are the options in a [Kickstart installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility). Instead, I would like to suggest you add a script to run after the install, as [this link describes](http://blog.self.li/post/74294988486/creating-a-post-installation-script-for-ubuntu).